# Why is requirejs respecting the data-main entry point for some modules, but not others?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, assetic

My program starts through this entry point in a twig template:

```
<script data-main="{{ asset('bundles/wwwcms/js/app') }}" src="{{ asset('bundles/wwwcms/js/require.js') }}"></script>
```

This outputs:

```
<script data-main="static.correct_require_url.net/js/app" src="static.correct_require_url/require.js"></script>
```

That all works fine, so require executes my app.js (config):

```
requirejs.config({
  'baseUrl': 'js/lib',
  'paths': {
    'app': '../app',
    'jquery': '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min',
    'bootstrap': '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min'
  },

  'shim': {
    'bootstrap': {
      deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
});

// always require jquery and bootstrap onload
requirejs(['bootstrap']);
```

Which also works.

The directory structure is as follows:
app.js
require.js
/lib
 - test.js
/app
 - dirty.js
 - import.js

Okay so here is where the error comes

For a page, let's say I want to load dirty.js and import.js.  dirty.js depends on jquery, and import.js depends on "test.js" (something I just made up for demonstration purposes).

So I load the dependencies on the page this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require(['app/dirty', 'app/import']);
</script>
```

When the page loads, dirty.js and import.js are loaded in just fine, from the correct url relative to "app".  However, the dependency for import.js (test.js) does not get loaded correctly.

This is how import.js starts:

```
require(['jquery', 'test'], function($, test) {
...
});
```

As you can see, it's asking for lib/test.js.  It pulls jQuery from a CDN, so that's taken care of.  But for test.js, it uses the wrong path.

import.js (and all other modules loaded first) are pulled in using the correct static url path, but dependencies for modules are loaded using the wrong path- they are loaded using the url of that page!

So when I look at the network tab in the debugger console, import.js comes from:
static.blahblah.com/js/app/import.js.

but test.js comes from:
blahblah.com/route/to/current/page/js/app/test.js

(which obviously 404s every time)

What are possible reasons for this occurring?  Am I doing something wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is how the script tags look before require runs:

```
<script data-main="//static.bananajams.cloud.net/bundles/wwwcms/js/app" src="//static.bananajams.cloud.net/bundles/wwwcms/js/require.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  require(['app/dirty', 'app/preview', 'app/import']);
</script>
```

Comment: @Louis okay I showed them!

Comment: @Louis okay I see. I updated it again.

Comment: @ThePuma is there a reason you are not using [`define()`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) for your modules?

Comment: @sweetamylase that's just because I was trying to debug this issue and changed them over to require.  They should be/are using define().

Comment: In your requirejs.config, you map "test" to "app/test", which doesn't match your directory layout.  Try getting rid of that configuration.

Comment: @StepanRiha I did :-\.  It doesn't have to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically data-main is only a good idea if it's the single entry point for your code. It's loaded asynchronously, so there is no guarantees it runs before the other code in your app. See

[RequireJS does not run data-main script before loading required modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637042/requirejs-does-not-run-data-main-script-before-loading-required-modules)

for more info on this.